# Change default display name to username in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a WP site with membership and forum plugins.

Upon registration people select their username, however the default display name is their First + Last name. This is not ideal, I need the display name to be the same as username. I added this code but doesn't seem to work:

```
function change_display_name( $user_id ) {
$info = get_userdata( $user_id );
$args = array(
‘ID’ => $user_id,
‘display_name’ => $info->username
);
wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action(‘user_register’,’change_display_name’);
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to mess around with this during the registration, why not change it when it gets used, via the `get_user_display_name` hook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
 `wp_insert_user` to register a user.
See [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)